# Kalman forecast of AR(1)

Tags: autoregressive, kalman-filter

I'm trying to work out the details of the proof of the following statement:

Suppose $\xi_t = \rho \xi_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$ is an AR(1) process.

Using Kalman filter, one can prove that $\mathbb{E}_t\{\xi_t\}$ follows an AR(2) dynamics  with:

$$\mathbb{E}_t\{\xi_t\} = \left(1 - \frac{\lambda}{\rho}\right) \left(\frac{1}{1-\lambda L} \right) \xi_t$$
where  $\lambda =  \rho(1-g)$ and  $g \in (0,1)$ is the Kalman gain and $L$ is the lag operator.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Kalman filter ? If so, then you need to write out the Kalman filter recursions by writing the AR(1) in state space form ( see Kohn and Ansley for how to transform from an ARIMA to state space form. I forget year and title  ). If you're not familiar with the Kalman filter, then you need to understand that first before dealing with the question. There are so many books and papers introducing the Kalman filter that I don't know what to recommend.

Comment: Yes I'm familiar, I was hoping though for a detailed proof of the statement

Comment: I would try it but I forget how to write the AR(1) in state space form. Once you do that, it shouldn't be too bad. Maybe someone else can pipe in here because, if I could do it, I would but I forget the first step which is key. Google for "writing the AR(1) in state space form" and see what comes up. I'm too busy riight now but if this is still unanswered when I get free, I'll try to take a closer look.

Comment: Hi: page 7 of this has it for AR(p) so let p = 1 and go from there. http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~stine/stat910/lectures/14_state_space.pdf. Like I said, if I get time later, I'll give it a shot. It's been a looooooooong time !!!!

Comment: Thank you! Let me know if somebody figured it out, I'm still working on it.

Comment: Hi: I believe the statement if  you say so but could you tell me where you got that statement from ? I'm trying to find anything related and I haven't been able to. Thanks.

Comment: This is the paper: https://www.nber.org/system/files/working_papers/w24545/w24545.pdf

Comment: Thanks. What section or page is that result on ?

Comment: Proposition 2 at page 10 and following discussion.

Comment: I didn't get very far and I'm already confused. Does equation(15) make any sense to you ? It doesn't to me because the same thing in the expectation is on the right hand side also ?  I don't know what the greek letter is for it but it's possibly eta ?

Comment: It's called csi :) It makes sense because the error term is not observed when taking expectations!

Comment: But isn't it like having $E(X) = $ stuff $ \times X$. If one knows X ( which seems to be the case since it's on the RHS ), then what is it an expectation of ?

Comment: The formula just links the dynamics of $\xi_t$ to that of its expectation. If you observe $\xi_t$ then you can compute the expectation. But if you need to forecast $\mathbb{E}_{t+1}(\xi_{t+1})$ you need its dynamics.  For example, the forecast of the expectation will be given by $\alpha \mathbb{E}_{t}(\xi_{t}) + \beta \mathbb{E}_{t-1}(\xi_{t-1})$ for some coefficients $\alpha$ and $\beta$ given by the formula in the question.

Comment: The reason for why it is interesting 
 is here in section 3 (page 9) https://www.nber.org/system/files/working_papers/w24545/w24545.pdf